# Is there a way to tell VS Code to supply matching braces inside of quotation marks, at least in Python files?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Typically VS Code supplies a matching pair of parentheses, braces, and brackets when you type an opening character. But when you are inside of quotation marks, VS Code apparently gives up on this behavior, assuming that you are writing free text and not code. So you don't get a closing brace automatically; you have to type it yourself. This is sub-optimal in Python.

In Python, so-called f-strings allow you to embed variables inside of strings. So you will often need to write matching braces inside of quotation marks, like so:

```py
print(f"Let's talk about {some_variable}.")
```

When you type the opening brace inside the quotation marks, VS Code does not supply the closing brace—again, because VS Code apparently assumes you aren't writing code.

Is there a way to change this behavior so that VS Code will supply a closing brace inside of quotation marks? If not, could this feature be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't way to have them inserted automatically. As for as a feature request, you can open one at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python (it is probably doable as VS Code does it for TypeScript with backticks).

Comment: Thank you! I've heard your name (and maybe even an interview) on Python Bytes or Talk Python, so I feel like a celebrity has commented on my question!

Comment: I created an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13673 - please consider upvoting or commenting if it makes sense to you. Thanks again!